# Why radio button switching is not reflecting in redux state variable?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on a react.js app where i am working with redux state management.I have created 2 radio buttons and I am switching between them and setting the state variable correspondingly.

Here's my active button:

```
    <form >
      <input type="radio" id="html" name="status" value="HTML" onClick={this.setClientStatus("Active")}/>
      <label for="html">Active</label><br/>
      <input type="radio" id="css" name="status" value="CSS" onClick={this.setClientStatus("InActive")}/>
      <label for="css">InActive</label><br/>
   </form>
```

Here's my dispatch method:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setClientName: clientName=>dispatch(onSetClientName(clientName)),
  setClientStatus:clientStatus=>dispatch(onSetClientStatus(clientStatus))
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(toReturn);
```

Here's my method to change the state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setClientStatus=this.setClientStatus.bind(this);
  }
    setClientStatus(status)
      {
        this.props.setClientStatus(status)
      }
```

`action.js`

```
export const SET_STATUS='CLIENT/SET_STATUS'
```

`actionCreator.js`

```
export function onSetClientStatus(clientStatus)
{
  // console.log(clientStatus)
  return {type:Actions.SET_STATUS,clientStatus}
}
```

`clientReducer.js`

```
   const initialState = {
  clientStatus:"",
};
case Actions.SET_STATUS:{
      
      {
        console.log(action.clientStatus)
        return Object.assign({},state,{clientStatus:action.clientStatus})}
    }
```

Even when I try to log the status in actionCreator or reducer,without clicking on radio buttons I see toggling in value of status whenever the state of app changes due to other state variables.I am calling the setClientStatus method only on `onClick` of radio buttons but I dont know how they are getting logged on every state change in the app.

Here's my full working app.use `npm start` to run then go to `add a client` then just toggle between the radio buttons.

Github repo [here](https://github.com/Himanshuranjan30/ClientDash2)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `onClick` prop of both your inputs you are invoking the `setClientStatus` instead of passing a function. It happens on every render, that's why you see it being toggled on other state changes.

Instead of:

```
onClick={this.setClientStatus("Active")}
onClick={this.setClientStatus("InActive")}
```

you probably need to have:

```
onClick={() => this.setClientStatus("Active")}
onClick={() => this.setClientStatus("InActive")}
```

Comment: Thanks for this,cant believe I missed that